# Open PDF file in react-native with expo

Tags: react-native, pdf, expo

I'm using React Native with Expo and I'm trying to open a pdf file. I already have the file in my assets folder. I prefer to not detach expo.

I tried to use `react-native-pdf` like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, View } from 'react-native';

import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';

export default class PDFExample extends Component {
  render() {
    const source = {uri:'bundle-assets://test.pdf'};
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pdf
          source={source}
          style={styles.pdf} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 25,
  },
  pdf: {
    flex:1,
    width:Dimensions.get('window').width,
  }
});
```

But no success. Many errors occur and I'm losing faith in this package. So I'm looking for a simpler solution.

**The question:**
How can I open a asset file in another app. Like, making ios or android choose which app will open the pdf file. Can I do that with only managed code in expo without detach?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Didn't find any solution so far.

Comment: See my solution that's working well for Expo 38+. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69117954/12960247

Answer (score 3):

Install the following libraries via yarn or npm:
`yarn add react-native-webview expo-file-system expo-constants rn-pdf-reader-js`

Then you can display a PDF like so:

```js
import React from ‘react’
import { ScrollView, View, } from ‘react-native’
import PDFReader from ‘rn-pdf-reader-js’

export default class Publications extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <PDFReader
               source={{
               uri: ‘http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf’,
               }}
          />
       )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found is using Adobe PDF Embed API. Using it in the react-native-webview does the job.

[Adobe Pdf Embed API](https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/apis/pdf-embed/)

What I did is that I create a new component and passed the pdf url as its props and then displaying it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

function PdfViewScreen({route}) {
  const pdfUrl = route.params;

  const myHtml = `<html><body>
      <div id="adobe-dc-view"></div>
      <script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function(){
          var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
          adobeDCView.previewFile({
            content:{ location:
              { url: '${pdfUrl}'}},
            metaData:{fileName: "Dummy name"}
          },
          {
            embedMode: "SIZED_CONTAINER"
          });
        });
    </script>
  </body></html>`


    return (
  
            <WebView 
              originWhitelist={['*']} 
              source={{ html : myHtml}}
              onMessage={(event) => {
                alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
              }} 
            />

    );
}


export default PdfViewScreen;
```